# how to remove empty series from list in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list which looks something like this.

```
DB
Out[469]: 
[[3    523
Name: order_id, dtype: object], 0    [526, 533]
Name: order_id, dtype: object, Series([], Name: order_id, dtype: object)]
```

And what I want it to look like this.

```
DB
[['523',['526','533']]]
```

I am doing following in python

```
 DB[0][0].values[0]
 Out[462]: '523'

 DB[1][0]
 Out[463]: ['526', '533']
```

And to remove empty series

```
 [x for x in DB if x != []]
```

But It doesn't work. I want a for loop which will iterate through `DB` and give me final output. Please help.

Comment: actually does this work: `[x for x in l if len(x)>0]`?

Comment: Could you post code to create that list?

Comment: @AntonProtopopov  I can't post the code because its a long function.

Comment: @AntonProtopopov I get this after slicing a dataframe by groupby and them I am appending it to the empty list.

Comment: @AntonProtopopov  Eventually I was able to get `[[['523']], [['526', '533']]]` this now how can I remove the extra brackets.

Comment: Can you post raw data and code to reproduce your series, at the moment this is all very ambiguous

Answer (score 2):

test for the `len` inside your list comprehension to remove it:

```
In [150]:
l=[pd.Series(['asda']), pd.Series(), pd.Series([9,12,4])]
l

Out[150]:
[0    asda
 dtype: object, Series([], dtype: float64), 0     9
 1    12
 2     4
 dtype: int64]

In [153]:    
[x for x in l if len(x)>0]

Out[153]:
[0    asda
 dtype: object, 0     9
 1    12
 2     4
 dtype: int64]
```

You can see that the lengths are different:

```
In [155]:
print(len(l))
print(len([x for x in l if len(x)>0]))

3
2
```

Comment: Yup, `len(x)>0` is working and its removing empty series,but how can i convert the elements to the desired format

Comment: you mean `[x.values.tolist() for x in l if len(x)>0]`?

Comment: Yup. I ran `[x.values.tolist() for x in l if len(x)>0]` but its giving me error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'`

Comment: Try that: `[x.values.tolist() if type(x)==pd.Series else x for x in l if len(x) > 0]`

Comment: @AntonProtopopov Thanks for your help. I ran what you suggested its giving me following output `[x.values.tolist() if type(x)==pd.Series else x for x in DB if len(x) > 0]
Out[482]: 
[[3    523
  Name: order_id, dtype: object], [['526', '533']]]`

Comment: @AntonProtopopov  Its not converting first element to list i.e `['523']`

Comment: One more time: `[x.values.tolist() if isinstance(x, (pd.Series, pd.DataFrame)) else x for x in l if len(x) > 0]`

Comment: @AntonProtopopov  Still gives me a same output

Comment: Could you post output from `[type(x) for x in l]`?

Comment: @AntonProtopopov  `[list, pandas.core.series.Series]`